# Jquery change only one paragraph by clicking the chekbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

So I have a checkbox and a paragraph in my rails app -

```
<li class="task" id="task_<%= task.id %>" >
  <%= check_box_tag task.id, task.id, task.mark, class: "task-check" %>
  <label for=<%=task.id %> ></label>
    <p><%= task.content %></p>
```

And I want to toggle paragraphs' class by clicking on the checkbox

I've write some Jquery function to change task status (that's not so important,but maybe you'll want to know it) and to toggle the class -

```
$(".task-check").on('click', function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/tasks/'+this.value+'/mark',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"mark": this.checked}
      });
      $('p').toggleClass('done')
  });
```

But it changes all paragraph on the page,so I'm missing `this` as I think,but I can't figure out where should I put `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

```
$(".task-check").on('change', function(){
    // always cache the element, this increase the performance,
    // also in javascript, `this` is too tricky and may change inside blocks
    // so by caching, you can always trust chached item
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/tasks/'+ $this.val() +'/mark',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"mark": $this.is(':checked') }
    });

    $this.next().toggleClass('done');
    // OR if `p` isn't next item (if so, maybe you should add `class` to p,
    // so you can find that easily)
    // $this.parent().find('p.MY-CLASS').toggleClass('done');
});
```

Comment: @Mikhah What about now?

Comment: The class 'done' is now adding to the checbox, but not to the paragraph

Comment: Did you change your code exactly same as mine? Could you please share rendered html?

Comment: So, use commented way in my answer `$this.parent().find('p').toggleClass('done');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".task-check").on('click', function(){
  $(this).next('p').toggleClass('done');
});
```

> Why you call ajax? if you need toggle class, you not need to call ajax

Answer (score 0):

you need to seperate the event from the DOM element.
event is the trigger, and the DOM element has it own properties

```js
var A = window,
    B = document,
    a = function(a){return B.getElementById(a);};
    
a('checkbox').onclick = function(){
  if(this.checked === true){
    a('parag').setAttribute('class','b');
  } else {
    a('parag').setAttribute('class','a');
  }
};
```

```css
.a{color:#000;}
.b{color:blue;}
```

```html
<p id="parag" class="a">This is paragraph</p><br />

checkbox: <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

> You can try this.
>   if you need ajax call ajax. 
>   are you call jQuery in top of html?

```
$(".task-check").on('change', function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).next('p').addClass('done');
  }else{
    $(this).next('p').removeClass('done');
  }
});
```